# How do I go about setting TextView to display UTF-8 when the String is not an embedded Resource?

Tags: android, json, utf-8, textview

I'm encountering an odd situation whereby strings that I load from my resource XML file that have Spanish characters in them display correctly in my TextViews, but strings that I'm fetching from a JSON file that I load via HTTP at runtime display the missing char [] boxes

`ESPAÑOL` for example, when embedded in my XML strings works fine, but when pulled from my JSON is rendered as SPAÃ[]OL, so the Ñ is transformed into a Ã and a missing char!

I'm not sure at what point I need to intercept these strings and set the correct encoding on them.  The JSON text file itself is generated on the server via Node, so, I'm not entirely sure if that's the point at which I should be encoding it, or if I should be encoding the fileReader on the Android side, or perhaps setting the TextView itself to be of some special encoding type (I'm unaware that this is an option, just sort of throwing my hands in the air, really).

[EDIT]
As per  ianhanniballake's suggestion I am logging and seeing that the screwy characters are actually showing up in the log as well. However, when I look at the JSON file with a text viewer on the Android file system (it's sitting on the SDCARD) it appears correct.

Comment: Does logcat (which does support UTF-8) show the correct characters? That would ensure that your input side is processing it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turned out that the text file was, indeed, encoded correctly and the issue was that I wasn't setting UTF-8 as my encoding on the FileInputStream...

The solution is to read the file thusly:

```
static String readInput() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile.json");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            buffer.append((char) ch);
        }
        in.close();
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```